# C Shared Memory Seg Fault

Tags: c, shared-memory, mmap

I'm working on a project using shared memory right now and am getting a mind-boggling seg fault.  For some reason not all of the memory I'm allocating to *node is accessible.  At a certain index(the same every run of the program) the memory cannot be written to.  Below is my code, and some output.

```
int shf = shm_open("/queue", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
int success = ftruncate(shf, sizeof(QNode)*numVertices*numVertices);
QNode *node = (QNode*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(QNode)*numVertices*numVertices, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shf, 0); 

int a, b;
for (a=0; a<numVertices; a++) {
    for (b=0; b<numVertices; b++) {
        (node[sizeof(QNode)*a*numVertices + sizeof(QNode)*b]).k = a;                
        (node[sizeof(QNode)*a*numVertices + sizeof(QNode)*b]).i = b;
        printf("Mapping to offset %d\ti:%d\tk:%d\n", sizeof(QNode)*a*numVertices + sizeof(QNode)*b, (node[sizeof(QNode)*a*numVertices + sizeof(QNode)*b]).i,(node[sizeof(QNode)*a*numVertices + sizeof(QNode)*b]).k);
    }
}
```

Output on smaller graph:

```
// Bunch of output
Offset: 472 i:5 k:6
Offset: 480 i:6 k:6
Offset: 488 i:7 k:6
Offset: 496 i:8 k:6
Offset: 504 i:0 k:7
Offset: 512 i:1 k:1
Offset: 520 i:1 k:1
Offset: 528 i:1 k:0
Offset: 536 i:1 k:1
Offset: 544 i:1 k:1
Offset: 552 i:1 k:0
Offset: 560 i:0 k:0
// More incorrect output down here
```

On the larger graph output below, there is some more puzzling results that I can't post here-- at offset 7168, it begins printing out non-printable characters.  For example, on the line for offset 7168 I see Ma[NUL][NUL][NUL][NUL][SI][NUL][NUL][NUL] offset 7168...  Here's the output I can actually show you for the larger graph-- after the last line it seg faults.

Output on a larger graph:

```
// Bunch of output
Mapping to offset 9136  i:54    k:17
Mapping to offset 9144  i:55    k:17
Mapping to offset 9152  i:56    k:17
Mapping to offset // This is where it seg faults...
```

Any help is tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm... do truly mean to index like `node[sizeof(QNode)*a*numVertices + sizeof(QNode)*b]`? C automatically multiplies your indexes by the size of the struct being pointed to, so I feel like `node[a*numVertices + b]` would look more sane.